# Linux: Run Python without installation

Tags: java, python, linux, installation, portable-executable

My company server install Redhat 6 with Python 2.6 default. The customer send me some sample code using Python 3.4 but I have not permission to install Python 3.4

Using Java, I can copy the jdk installation folder from another Linux server to mine without install it. The only change I need to do is to change you JAVA_HOME and PATH variable accordingly

How can I apply this way for Python?

Comment: Try [Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) ([`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)).

Comment: You can download and compile from source, but not install it system-wide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `python.org` and download its source code, such as "Python-3.4.6.tar.xz", then extract it, change your directory to the root and run this script:

```sh
./configure; make
```

Here is also a shell script, and you could run it.

```
# get-python3.sh
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.6/Python-3.4.6.tar.xz
tar xvfJ Python-3.4.6.tar.xz
cd Python-3.4.6
./configure
make
```

Finally, you could run python by `./python` command.

Here is output:

```
Python 3.4.6 (default, Mar 20 2017, 20:03:28) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```